# ¿Como puedo listar por artista en un arraylist?

Tags: java

estoy realizando un ejercicio donde tengo que hacer un menú de una playlist con añadir canciones etcetc.. Y tambien tengo que listar las canciones por artista, Tengo el metodo main y el metodo Musica dicho de otra manera donde se encuentran los metodos , constructores etc. Lo que no me esta saliendo es que al pasar y añadir el artista no me encuentra nada dentro de la arraylist , con datos ya dentro , Os paso el código para que me podais ayudar

Muchas Gracias

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean salida = false;
        int option;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Musica musica=new Musica();

        String SongName;
        String Artista = null;
        String Genero;
        int popular = 0;
        int Any;
        String hastags;

        do {
            System.out.println("1.Add a new song to Playlist");
            System.out.println("2.Delete song from Playlist");
            System.out.println("3.List songs by artist");
            System.out.println("4.List top 5 songs with a specific hastag");
            System.out.println("5.Exit");
            try {
                System.out.print("Please choose an option:");
                option = scanner.nextInt();

                switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("SongName?:");
                         SongName=scanner.nextLine();
                         scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Artist?:");
                        Artista=scanner.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("Genre?:");
                        Genero=scanner.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("Year?:");
                        Any=scanner.nextInt();

                        musica.addSong(SongName,Artista,Genero,Any);

                        System.out.println("How popular is this?[1-10]");
                        popular=scanner.nextInt();

                        System.out.println("Add some hastags to the song: #w,#y : ");
                        scanner.nextLine();
                        hastags=scanner.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("You range is "+" " +popular+ "And your hastags is "+" "+hastags);



                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("You choose delete song");


                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("You choose List songs by artist");
                        musica.listSong();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("You choose List top 5 songs with a specific hastag");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        salida = true;
                        System.out.println("May the Music be with you");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Only numbers from 1 to 5");
                }

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("You need to enter an input");
                scanner.next(); //Evitamos que entre en bucle
            }


        }while (!salida) ;
    }
}
```

Os paso la Clase Musica donde tengo todos los metodos y constructores de las canciones , items etc

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Musica {

    private String SongName;
    private String Artist;
    private String Genre;
    private int Year;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Musica> songs = new ArrayList<>();

    public Musica(String SongName, String Artist, String genre, int year) {
        this.SongName = SongName;
        this.Artist = Artist;
        this.Genre = genre;
        this.Year = year;

    }

    public Musica() {

    }


    public void addSong(String SongName, String Artist, String Genre, int Year) {
        songs.add(new Musica(SongName, Artist, Genre, Year));
    }


    public void listSong() {

        for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(songs.get(i));
            }





    }
```

Comment: El primer error que veo en tu código es que metes dentro de `Musica` un `Scanner` y un ArrayList de objetos de la misma clase `Musica`. Ninguna de las dos cosas tienen sentido. **Piensa la POO de una forma lógica, como funciona en la realidad misma**, esto te ayudará a no cometer errores de diseño, además la POO se creó con esos fines. Si `Musica` es un objeto que guardará varias canciones, entonces debes tener una clase `Song` o `Cancion` y dentro de `Musica` manejar un objeto como este: `ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();` al cual irías agregando cada canción.

Comment: Además la clase debería llamarse `PlayList`, no `Musica`. Como dije antes, si no piensas la POO como en la realidad, pronto estarás perdido en tu propio laberinto de código.

Comment: Okay , Muchas Gracias ahora lo arreglo!

Answer (score -1):

En el código te faltaba el método ToString. Además tenías un error en el main que no se mostraba el nombre de las canciones. Pienso que es debido a un error de buffer. Lo que he hecho ha sido poner un .nextLine antes de definir el nombre de la canción. Además te he hecho un arraylist estático y he cambiado el nombre de algunas variables para poder realizar las pruebas. A continuación te dejo el código del main y el código de la clase música. Cualquier duda que tengas pregúntame. Un saludo.

clase main:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean salida = false;
    int option;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String nombrecancion = null;
    String Artista = null;
    String Genero = null;
    int popular = 0;
    int Any = 0;
    String hastags = null;

    do {
        System.out.println("1.Add a new song to Playlist");
        System.out.println("2.Delete song from Playlist");
        System.out.println("3.List songs by artist");
        System.out.println("4.List top 5 songs with a specific hastag");
        System.out.println("5.Exit");
        try {
            System.out.print("Please choose an option:");
            option = sc.nextInt();

            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("SongName?:");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    nombrecancion = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Artist?:");
                    Artista = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Genre?:");
                    Genero = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Year?:");
                    Any = sc.nextInt();

                    Musica.addSong(nombrecancion, Artista, Genero, Any);

                    System.out.println("How popular is this?[1-10]");
                    popular = sc.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("Add some hastags to the song: #w,#y : ");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    hastags = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("You range is " + " " + popular + " And your hastags is " + " " + hastags);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("You choose delete song");

                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("You choose List songs by artist");
                    Musica.listSong();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("You choose List top 5 songs with a specific hastag");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    salida = true;
                    System.out.println("May the Music be with you");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Only numbers from 1 to 5");
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("You need to enter an input");
            sc.next(); // Evitamos que entre en bucle
        }

    } while (!salida);
}}
```

Clase musica:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Musica {

private String nombrecancion;
private String Artist;
private String Genre;
private int Year;
private static ArrayList<Musica> songs = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * @param songName
 * @param artist
 * @param genre
 * @param year
 */
public Musica(String nombrecancion, String artist, String genre, int year) {
    this.nombrecancion = nombrecancion;
    this.Artist = artist;
    this.Genre = genre;
    this.Year = year;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Nombre de la cancion {" + nombrecancion + "} Artista {" + Artist + "} Género {" + Genre + "} Año {"
            + Year + "}";
}

static void addSong(String SongName, String Artist, String Genre, int Year) {
    songs.add(new Musica(SongName, Artist, Genre, Year));
}

public static void listSong() {

    for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(songs.get(i));
    }

}}
```

Comment: La idea es que en listSong tú le metas el nombre del artista y si encuentra al artista pues que salgan las canciones

Comment: Entiendo. Dame un ratito y te lo respondo

Comment: Perfecto, Muchas Gracias es ahí donde me he quedado pillado

Comment: Este diseño es pésimo y la respuesta en vez de ayudar, confunde y fomenta **malas prácticas** ¿Cómo explicas que `Musica` contenga un array de sí misma:  `private static ArrayList<Musica> songs = new ArrayList<>();`? La POO surgió para facilitar las cosas, programando conforme a la realidad. Tú no puedes contener un array de ti mismo, eso sería una aberración.

Comment: Señor experto POO porque no ayuda usted al que formuló la pregunta en ve de quejarse? Soy un estudiante y estoy intentando ayudar sé perfectamente que no está bien ese arraylist pero no voy a crearle otra clase, el lo que está pidiendo es X cosa y tu estás yendo a otra.

Comment: Simplemente he creado un método toString para que imprima las canciones añadidas. Nada más. creo recordar que ha preguntado como filtrar las canciones por nombre de artista. No como estructurar un código.

Comment: Exacto, es esoo

Comment: @JosepGiner si la respuesta te sirvió recuerda aceptarla o puntuarla, recuerda que muchos dedican tiempo y esfuerzo para poder responder. Toma en cuenta las observaciones que te han hecho anteriormente, ya que a lo mejor en este momento no lo necesites, pero conforme avances veras la importancia de ellas.

Comment: He intentado ayudar, en forma de comentario, aunque sea molesto. Ahora bien, OP puede optar por el camino fácil, ignorando comentarios incómodos, lo cual no quita que sea un mal diseño. OP respondió a mi comentario: *ahora lo **arreglo***, interpreté que había comprendido que estaba mal y que se esforzaría por mejorar su código, aprendiendo más sobre POO. Pero no ha arreglado nada. Si me hubiese dicho: *entiendo, pero no sé como hacerlo* quizá habría aportado una respuesta. Créeme, no quiero fastidiar con mi comentario, sólo contribuir a una respuesta de calidad y didáctica.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo he arreglado en mi Intellij aquí no lo he puesto aún