# ¿Como puedo borrar una linea de Arraylist introduciendo un dato por teclado?

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo problemas con esta parte del código en el que tengo que borrar una linea de Arraylist introduciendo una canción mediante teclado y que luego en el Arraylist busque y si encuentra dicha canción entonces lo borra .  Os paso el main y la clase Playlist para que le podais echar un vistazo y me podais ayudar para poder solucionarlo , ya que personalmente he ido intentandolo por mi solo pero no hay manera de sacarlo

Clase Playlist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Playlist {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String nombrecancion;
    private String Artist;
    private String Genre;
    private int Year;


    /**
     * @param songName
     * @param artist
     * @param genre
     * @param year
     */

    private static ArrayList<Playlist> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    public Playlist(String nombrecancion, String Artist, String genre, int year) {
        this.nombrecancion = nombrecancion;
        this.Artist = Artist;
        this.Genre = genre;
        this.Year = year;

    }
    public Playlist(){

    }

     public static void addSong(String SongName, String Artist, String Genre, int Year) {
        songs.add(new Playlist(SongName, Artist, Genre, Year));
    }

    public  void deleteSong(String SongName, String Artist, String Genre, int Year){
        String cancion;
        System.out.println("Entra canción");
        cancion=sc.nextLine();

        boolean busqueda=songs.contains(cancion);

        songs.remove(SongName);


    }

    public static void listSong() {


            for (int i=0;i<songs.size();i++){
                System.out.println(songs.get(i));
            }
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nombre de la cancion : " + nombrecancion + " Artista : " + Artist + " Género: " + Genre + " Año :"
                + Year + "";
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return Artist;
    }

    public static void listmenu(){
        System.out.println("1.Add a new song to Playlist");
        System.out.println("2.Delete song from Playlist");
        System.out.println("3.List songs by artist");
        System.out.println("4.List top 5 songs with a specific hastag");
        System.out.println("5.Exit");
    }
}




Main
```

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    boolean salida = false;
    int option;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Playlist playlist=new Playlist();
    String nombrecancion = null;
    String Artista = null;
    String Genero = null;
    int popular = 0;
    int Any = 0;
    String hastags = null;

    do {
        Playlist.listmenu();
        try {
            System.out.print("Please choose an option:");
            option = sc.nextInt();

            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("SongName?:");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    nombrecancion = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("Artist?:");
                    Artista = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("Genre?:");
                    Genero = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("Year?:");
                    Any = sc.nextInt();

                    Playlist.addSong(nombrecancion, Artista, Genero, Any);

                    System.out.println("How popular is this?[1-10]");
                    popular = sc.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("Add some hastags to the song: #w,#y : ");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    hastags = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("You range is " + " " + popular + " And your hastags is " + " " + hastags);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("You choose delete song");
                    playlist.deleteSong();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("You choose List songs by artist");

                    String Artistas;

                    System.out.println("Enter an Artist");
                    Artistas=sc.nextLine();


                    Playlist.listSong();

                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("You choose List top 5 songs with a specific hastag");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    salida = true;
                    System.out.println("May the Music be with you");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Only numbers from 1 to 5");
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("You need to enter an input");
            sc.next(); // Evitamos que entre en bucle
        }

    } while (!salida);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al tu declarar el `ArrayList<PlayList> songs` como atributo de tu clase `PlayList` este solo podra ser accedido desde esa misma clase y no en otra,aunque tu solucion haya sido declararla como `static` e invocarla en la clase `main` mediante el método que lo aplica

```
Playlist.addSong
```

esto hace que pierda el sentido declarar `Playlist playlist=new Playlist();`ya que nunca haces uso del objeto..entonces por que usar paradigma `POO` si te aferras a un estilo de programación `estructurada`, la información que te brindo A.cedano en tu anterior [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562866/como-puedo-listar-por-artista-en-un-arraylist) bien podria resolver y aclarar los problemas en tu codigo.. y es que una `playList` es un conjunto de `canciones` y asu vez una de esa canciones tiene *titulo,artista,genero año etc* esto bien lo podrias manejar en una clase independiente

```
public class Cancion{

    private String nombreCancion;
    private String artist;
    private String genre;
    private int year;
    //Contructor
    public Cancion(String nombreCancion,String artist,String genre,int year){
    this.nombreCancion=nombreCancion;
    this.artist=artist;
    this.genre=genre;
    this.year=year;
    }
    //GETTERS AND SETTERS 

    //ToString
    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return "\nNombre de la Cancion: "+nombreCancion+
           "\nArtista: "+artist+
           "\nGenero: "+genre+
           "\nYear: "+year;
    }
}
```

teniendo la clase `canción` ahora podes generar la clase `PlayList` la cual tendrá una lista de canciones

```
public class Playlist { 
    private ArrayList<Cancion> songs;//lista de canciones
//Inicializa el ArrayList dentro del constructor para que cada nuevo objeto de tu clase PlayList tenga su propia lista de canciones
    public Playlist() {
    this.songs=new ArrayList<>();
    }
  
    public  void addSong(Cancion Cancion) {
        songs.add(Cancion);
    }
//para borrar una `Cancion`necesitaras el nombre de esta y luego iterar la lista donde esta guardada de haber coincidencia usas el metodo remove
    public  void deleteSong(String songName){
        boolean busqueda=false;
        Cancion buscado=null;
        for(Cancion m:songs){
          if(m.getNombreCancion().equals(songName)){
              busqueda=true;
              buscado=m;  
          }
        }
        if(busqueda){
              songs.remove(buscado);
              System.out.println("Cancion eliminada"); }
        else{
            System.out.println("No se encontro la cancion");
        }
    }
//similar al metodo deleteSong()
    public void listSongByArtist(String artist){
         boolean busqueda=false;
         for(Cancion m:songs){
          if(m.getArtist().equals(artist)){
             System.out.println(m);
             busqueda=true;
          }
         }
         if(!busqueda){
             System.out.println("No se encontro al artista");
         }
    }
}
```

ahora solo haces uso de tus métodos en la clase `Main`

```
public class Main {
public static void listmenu(){
        System.out.println("1.Add a new song to Playlist");
        System.out.println("2.Delete song from Playlist");
        System.out.println("3.List songs by artist");
        System.out.println("4.List top 5 songs with a specific hastag");
        System.out.println("5.Exit");
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean salida = false;
    int option;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Playlist playlist=new Playlist();
    String nombrecancion = null;
    String artista = null;
    String genero = null;
    int popular = 0;
    int any = 0;
    String hastags = null;
    String artistas=null;
    String cancionEliminada=null;

    do {
        listmenu();
        try {
            System.out.print("Please choose an option:");
            option = sc.nextInt();

            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("SongName?:");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    nombrecancion = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Artist?:");
                    artista = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Genre?:");
                    genero = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Year?:");
                    any = sc.nextInt();
                    playlist.addSong(new Cancion(nombrecancion, artista, genero, any));
                    System.out.println("How popular is this?[1-10]");
                    popular = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Add some hastags to the song: #w,#y : ");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    hastags = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("You range is " + " " + popular + " And your hastags is " + " " + hastags);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("You choose delete song");
                    System.out.println("enter the song, which you want to delete");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    cancionEliminada =sc.nextLine();
                    playlist.deleteSong(cancionEliminada);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("You choose List songs by artist");
                    System.out.println("Enter an Artist");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    artistas=sc.nextLine();
                    playlist.listSongByArtist(artistas);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("You choose List top 5 songs with a specific hastag");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    salida = true;
                    System.out.println("May the Music be with you");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Only numbers from 1 to 5");
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("You need to enter an input");
            sc.next(); // Evitamos que entre en bucle
        }

    } while (!salida);
}}
```

Menciones adicionales

-Procura que los metodos que declares tengan sentido con la clase donde las declaras

-Usa la notacion [camelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

-nombra las variables con minúscula

-Solo usa Scanner en la clase donde estará tu método main